# TypeError: admin.messaging.sendToDevice is not a function , using firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

While using the below function I am getting to send device to device notification I am getting this error in firebase cloud functions for messaging

> TypeError: admin.messaging.sendToDevice is not a function

```
return admin.messaging.sendToDevice(to_token_id,payload).then(result=>{

            console.log("Notification Sent Successful");
            return null;
        });
```

Is the above method deprecated?
If so, then what is the new one?
The above firebase cloud function is written in javascript.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes, I checked Your answer, it was helpful but with some modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendToDevice`, you need to use the method `send()`:

```
// The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
var topic = 'highScores';

var message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  topic: topic
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#build_send_requests